# Effects of copy (cp) vs cut (mv) on file systems

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-copy, defragmentation

When you have to move a file to a different location in the same file system, you have two options: just cut-paste (or `mv`), or copy-paste (`cp`) and then delete the old copy.

I'm wondering what are the effects on common Linux file systems (especially ext2/3/4) in terms of possible defragmentation and long-term file system health and efficiency. In other words, no matter which option is faster (of course `mv` is faster than `cp`), if you wanted to keep your file system as clean and efficient as possible over time, should you prefer `mv` or `cp`/`rm` when moving a file? Does it even matter in modern file systems?

Comment: There is no general answer to the question. Scenario 1: File is heavily fragmented due to almost full filesystem, other files are deleted, copy of file is not fragmented at all. Copy removes fragmentation. Scenario 2: File is not fragmented, filesystem gets almost full, copy leads to fragmentation. Of course, a mv within a filesytem is faster and causes less wear and tear. In my opinion, though, wear and tear can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

`cp` creates a duplicate copy of the data and then `rm` unlinks the original
this frees up the space allocated to the original (if it was singly linked).

`mv` is faster because it only creates and removes links (when both locations are on the same filesystem)

`cp -l` followed by `rm` would be roughly equivalent to `mv`.

cp+rm causes greater churn on the allocated blocks so this will have a larger effect on fragmentation.

Comment: Is "_a larger effect_" on fragmentation a good effect (i.e. less fragmentation) or a bad effect (i.e. more fragmentation)?

Comment: really I can't say much more than yes!   it could be good or bad depending on how much free space there is and how much fragmentation there is.

Comment: Mmm. I'm not sure that this answer addresses the question asked by the OP, "_if you wanted to keep your file system as clean and efficient as possible over time, should you prefer mv or cp/rm when moving a file?_"

Comment: there is no clear reason to prefer either.